# Django ForeignKey field type

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have a model Products:

```
class Products(models.Model):
       id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
       name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
       image = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
       status = models.IntegerField()
       """created_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
       updated_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)"""

       created_by = models.ForeignKey('User', db_column='created_by', related_name='created_product')
       updated_by = models.ForeignKey('User', db_column='updated_by', related_name='update_product')
       created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
       updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

the mysql shell shows the id field of type:

```
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
```

I'm trying to create a ForeignKey to this table in such a way:

```
class ProductVarieties(models.Model):
       id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
       product = models.ForeignKey(Products)
       variety = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
       created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
       updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

on running migrations, I get an error
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')`

If I do `describe product_varieties`, I get:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| variety    | varchar(200)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at | datetime(6)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at | datetime(6)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| product_id | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

> Notice type of `product_id` is showing `int(11)` instead of `int(10) unsigned`.

This means django isn't detecting the right field types for the foreign key.

Comment: Why have you made your id fields PositiveIntegerFields? Django won't detect that they are autoincrements, so you will have problems updating and inserting.

Comment: that's because using `models.AutoField` creates primary keys with `int(11)` instead of `int(10) unsigned`. I already have tables with `int(10) unsigned` in my table. I want to be able to make ForeignKey Relations to them.

Comment: Why you are not using default ids? If you want to use id as keys with other tables - you can make migrations, so any info wouldn't be lost.

Comment: Guys I don't think you're understanding the point here. If I use `AutoField` for primary keys, there is a conflict of type between `int(11) and int(10) unsigned` when creating `foreign keys`. Django doesn't let me specify the field type to use when creating `foreign keys`, and `mysql` won't let me create `foreign keys` from `int(11)` to `int(10) unsigned`.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what happened:

1. Your models are unmanaged (`managed = False` in Meta).
2. You have created the initial migration for the unmanaged target model `Products`.
3. You've then altered the primary key type.
4. Now you're trying to create the foreign key.

Then you need to delete the migration mentioned in 2) and then recreate it. Only then the correct type is passed to the foreign key.

Note that this may still go wrong, if PositiveIntegerField has an INT(NOT_10) as MySQL db representation.